# Touchpad tapping intermittent on Macbook Air

Tags: touchpad, macbook-air

On my 2010 Macbook Air, tapping on the touchpad works on about only half of the tap attempts. It seems the sensitivity or something is off. How can I fix this?

It looks like this [question has been asked before](https://askubuntu.com/q/36298/27980) and is unanswered.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in Precise 12.04 by default (i.e. it works with no xorg.confg or synclient scripts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you got the mactel extras: https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ppa (Adding this PPA to your system)

After having those installed, type in the following commands in your terminal (ctrl-alt-t)

```
synclient FingerHigh=120
synclient FingerLow=45
synclient PalmDetect=1
```

This makes the touchpad work much better for me :)

Comment: Just changing to the latest synaptics driver from "multithouch" seemed to work though with your settings, it seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The synaptics driver seems way more spotty than the multitouch driver. @Snicksie, do you have problems with the sensitivity of the synaptics driver?

Answer (score 1):

Via: http://uselessuseofcat.com/?p=74

Create a file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d named 60-synaptics.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "touchpad"
  Driver "synaptics"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Option "FingerHigh" "50"
  Option "RTCornerButton" "0"
  Option "RBCornerButton" "0"
  Option "MinSpeed" "0.7"
  Option "MaxSpeed" "1.7"
  Option "SHMConfig" "on"
  Option "TapAndDragGesture" "off"
  Option "PalmDetect" "on"
EndSection
```