# Dell Latitude 3340 Twitching mouse cursor when using touchpad or just resting 1 finger on touchpad!

Tags: mouse, dell, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

So I have been going through many of the forum posts here, even some who are addressing same issue as I have but not with a "real" fix!

My problem is the mouse pad, when I use ubuntu, acts erratic and twitchy. I can be trying just to move the cursor slowly and it will go nuts/acting up completely going up and down and to the sides very very fast and very very twitchy. The thing happens at random moments, which could be addressed to a pressure issue, but I don't think it is. It makes it impossible sometimes to just mark some text or click minimize on a window!!!!

What I so far found out is people say its most likely the pressure point, But I have tried that now and STILL have the problem (btw problem wasn't there in windows).

So far "only" thing I tried, as I'm scared of changing something major, is the PressureMotionMinZ, which I changed to 30 instead of the standard 15. But I have experienced the jumping mouse even after changing it. And its badly starting to annoy me. I have disabled as many functions on the touchpad as possible in hopes that it would be something like 2 fingers making the problem.

I am gonna try to reduce the PressureMotionMaxZ as the next thing, as It could seem to happen when I might apply too much pressure, but I don't think it is (worth a shot though).

Anyways, someone Please help! As this thing could be my end of using ubuntu, even though I enjoy it way more than Windows, this simple problem is starting to piss me off badly.

I seem to have found a way to force it out, If I rest my middle finger at the middle of the touchpad and then slowly move my two neighbor fingers towards the mouse pad/touchpad then it at a point starts jumping like crazy, until I lift the neighbor fingers again, like it recognize the other fingers before they even touch the touchpad or my middle finger reaches a specific pressure on the touchpad when I move the two other fingers... Im confused!

My current synclient settings:

Parameter settings:

```
LeftEdge                = 300
RightEdge               = 1700
TopEdge                 = 210
BottomEdge              = 1190
FingerLow               = 12
FingerHigh              = 15
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 107
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 141
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 48
HorizScrollDelta        = 48
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 1
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 0
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0819336
TouchpadOff             = 0
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 100
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 80
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 12
VertHysteresis          = 12
ClickPad                = 0
```

Comment: Have you also had issues where keyboard presses are repeated as if the key is being held down when it was only pressed once?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it types a key twice.

Answer (score 0):

Touchpad driver problem? I had a problem with my touchpad on a Dell Latitude 3340 with Ubuntu 12.04 preinstalled by Dell. My touchpad was not recognized as a touchpad. Funny that Dell sells stuff that are supposed to work out of the box, but they don't.

After a lot of searching, trial and error I got it fixed with these instructions:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2102346.html

Look at mikesmithv suggestion (7th answer from bottom up).

My touchpad works and is recognized as a touchpad.

Comment: That URL just gives me a white page... hopefully a temporary problem on ubuntuforums archive site. Reminds me of [this](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 0):

My similar problem on a Macbook 2,1 was solved by increasing the values of 
`HorizHysteresis` and `VertHysteresis` options in Synaptics. For those who have no idea how to do it, I described the procedure (with a different value being changed) in great detail in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/935467/307091).